# Excel file (from DataGridView) not showing 'Zero' for values < 1

Tags: excel, vb.net, cell-formatting

I'm exporting a DataGridView to an Excel file.

The DGV contains a column with currency (€) and so I'm using this code to format the Excel Sheet Column:

```
With xlSheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, C + 1), .Cells(1, C + 1)).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "€ #,###,###.00"
End With
```

But, when I open the saved excel file, if the value is < 1 (i.e. 0,25) I get:

> € ,25

instead of

> € 0,25

How can I fix?

Comment: Have you tried adding "\t" just before the value?

Comment: Shouldn't your number format be "€ #,###,##0.00" with the zero ahead of the decimal point, if you do want a digit to be displayed there?

Comment: @Capellan You're right! Post it as an answer so I'll be able to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a zero before the decimal point into your number format:

```
With xlSheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, C + 1), .Cells(1, C + 1)).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "€ #,###,##0.00"
End With
```

From this link - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

> 0 (zero) -- This digit placeholder displays insignificant zeros if a number has fewer digits than there are zeros in the format. For example, if you type 8.9, and you want it to be displayed as 8.90, use the format #.00.